# Anonymous union/structure holding a generic vector

Tags: c++, generics, vector, unions, anonymous

I'm trying to create an anonymous union that holds a generic vector in order to use it as a member in a class without naming the type_name of the union itself.

So that I could call the vector inside the class as following:

```
vec.size();
```

But my approach

```
template <typename T>
union{
  std::vector<T> vec;
};
```

will only give me the error "**template class without a name**". This also happens with structures. So does it not like to be anonymous when it is generic?

Search results just gave me the option to create a generic vector inside a named structure but, besides I couldn't get this to work either, I would loose the benefits of the anonymous union und I would need to call the vector e.g. as

```
struct_name.vec.size();
```

or even

```
class_name.struct_name.vec.size();
```

which I tried to avoid.

I want to make the vector generic so that it can store integers or doubles and I don't need to declare two different vectors with their own specific data types. Beside learning some principles of generics I also aim for lesser declarations and storage usage with this technique.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.  What is the problem with `std::vector<T>`?, why does it need to be in a containing object (structure or union)?  What is your perceived benefit of doing so?  Do you need one instance of `std::vector<>` to hold different types (using a variant or something similar)?

Comment: How do you plan to instantiate the template?

Comment: It can not be generic if it is written as `template <typename T> vector<T> vec;`
As far as I understood the template must be declared outside of the braces.
I want the template to be either integer or double to fill the vector with Fibonacci numbers.
So for every new or following number I could write `vec.push_back(fibonacci_function());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably do what you want. You need at least some way to discriminate at runtime if you have a vector of int or a vector of float.

With C++11 you might code

```
class StrangeVector {
    bool has_int;
    union {
        std::vector<int> vint;
        std::vector<float> vfloat;
    };
public:
    StrangeVector(bool withints) : has_int(withints) {
        if (withints) new(&vint) std::vector<int>();
        else new(&vfloat) std::vector<float>();
    }
    ~StrangeVector() {
        if (has_int) vint.~vector<int>();
        else vfloat.~vector<float>();
    }
};
```

But such code is really bad smelling. (I would suggest using a union of pointers, perhaps of smart pointers e.g. [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), or perhaps [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional); see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860960/how-should-one-use-stdoptional)).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857240/why-there-is-no-placement-delete-expression-in-c), or [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) ...

Notice that except for [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) typing information is used at *compile time* in C++.

Comment: Another option would be a templated impl ptr which implements an interface, which would be more scaleable to more types.

Comment: If I make my vector generic it, wouldn't it know I want to store integers when I call it like `vec<int>`?
But thank you for your quick answer! Apologize for my primitive questions, just started few weeks ago.