# std::experimental::optional<T> implementation: Constexpr constructor confusion

Tags: c++, option-type, constexpr, placement-new, c++17

While **implementing** `std::experimental::optional` ([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)) I got confused by the specification of a specific constructor, namely:

```
constexpr optional( const T& value ); // (4)
```

([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional))

This constructor allows `optional<T>`, for a trivially destructible type `T`, to be constructed in `constexpr` context. While the first requirement, namely switching off the user-provided destructor in this case to make `optional<T>` a literal type, is straight forward to solve, I do not know how to get around the limitation of **placement-new not being allowed in constexpr**.

I thought I was supposed to implement `optional<T>` using `std::aligned_storage<T>` to allow types `T` that are not default constructible and satisfy any alignment requirements, if applicable. But as I said, `constexpr` forbids me from using placement new in that particular constructor.

Did I have to much coffee and am not seeing an obvious solution here?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should one use std::optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860960/how-should-one-use-stdoptional)

Comment: @Matriac this is a question about the implementation side.

Comment: A `union` might work for this particular constructor, but I'm not confident it will be enough to handle all cases.

Comment: @hvd I am currently using tag dispatching to replace the placement new with an assignment in the case that `T` is trivially destructible. But I am not sure I will run into problems with classes containing things like `std::unique_ptr` (which would result in the class being trivially destructible) that will try to delete a garbage pointer once I assign to the buffer containing garbage.

Comment: libc++ uses a `union` for their implementation; https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/experimental/optional. So does gcc libstdc++; https://gnu.googlesource.com/gcc/+/gcc-5_3_0-release/libstdc++-v3/include/experimental/optional

Comment: Look at [this great articles](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/?s=optional).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not know how to get around the limitation of placement-new not being allowed in constexpr.

That is a correct diagnostic, literal types, `constexpr` and new expressions don’t mix. The most straightforward way to fulfil the various requirements of `std::experimental::optional<T>` is to implement it with variant members. Put plainly, a `union` has to be involved at some point. A quick sketch:

```
template<typename Val>
struct optional {
    union {
        Val optional_value;
        unsigned char dummy_byte;
    };
    bool filled;

    // post-condition: no-value state
    constexpr optional()
        : dummy_byte {}
        , filled(false)
    {}

    // post-condition: has-value state
    constexpr optional(Val const& val)
        : optional_value(val)
        , filled(true)
    {}

    // other special members omitted for brevity
};
```

<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25ecf84ba9558974)</kbd>

As a matter of fact, the old series of `optional` proposals used to [have a paragraph on the technique](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#implementability) to demonstrate that the requirements it put forth were reasonable at all. (Nowadays `std::experimental::optional` lives on in the various Library Fundamentals candidate TSs.)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I was so focused on aligned_storage, but this is the correct solution.